# cannot get out from directory by issuing the cd command

Tags: linux, csh

There is a certain directory, than when entered, i cannot get out anymore.

```
518 :cd ..
set: Syntax Error.
519 :cd
set: Syntax Error.
```

I get all the time the syntax error.

The name of the dir is my home dir and then .jenkins/workspace/x build/target.

For other directories it works

What can be the reason.

Can i somehow fix this directory?

There is an alias for cd

```
alias cd
set old=$cwd; chdir !*;
```

Comment: What is the name of the directory? Is there an alias for cd?

Comment: fixed description with your comments

Comment: Does the directory still exist?

Comment: You are using unquoted variables, that's the problem. ALWAYS use `"$var"` (or know why you shouldn't in each particular case). `"!*"` won't hurt either. (Though the real problem is using `csh` in the first place).

Comment: I wouldn't quote the !*. The idea is that it is several arguments and it should stay several arguments. In the case of cd maybe there is only one argument, but in general it is a bda idea to quote !*.

Comment: @ypnos You may have a point here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the set command syntax is correct. If you have a whitespace in your directory name, it fails. You have to protect it from that by quoting:

```
alias cd
set old="$cwd"; chdir !*;
```